# Preserve (or restore) lbound after casting from c_ptr

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a type that stores an array:

```
type data
  type(someType) pointer :: someTypePtr(:)
end type
```

I assign something to someTypePtr with

```
type(data), intent(inout) :: this
integer, intent(in) :: lb, ub
type(someType), target, intent(in) :: sometype(lb:ub)
this%someTypePtr => sometype
```

Later on I create a c_ptr pointing to the instance I just reffered to as *this*. When I cast this pointer back to a fortran type afterwards, the lower bound starts with 0:

```
type(c_ptr) :: ptr
type(someType) :: data
call c_f_pointer(ptr, data)
write(*,*) lbound(data%someTypePtr) !will give 0
```

Is there something similar to reshape to change the `someTypePtr` back to it's original `lbound:ubound`?

Comment: Your source snippets, as shown, are a little incomplete or have errors.  For example - data in the second snippet must have the POINTER attribute.  I'd expect a compiler diagnostic for that specific problem - but perhaps something else is missing from the example source that causes other problems.  Could you make sure those snippets are accurate and could you also please show the code that obtains the C_PTR.  What do you do with the C_PTR in between acquiring it and its use in the second fragment?  Which compiler/version/compile options are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange, it should be `1`, not `0`. Anyway, you can remap the pointer afterwards:

```
 use iso_c_binding
 real(c_float), pointer :: ptr(:)
 type(c_ptr) :: ptr_c

 allocate(ptr(5:6))

 ptr_c = c_loc(ptr(lbound(ptr)))
 call c_f_pointer(ptr_c, ptr, [2])

 print *, lbound(ptr)

 ptr(5:6) => ptr

 print *, lbound(ptr)
end
```

run:

```
> ./a.out 
           1
           5
```